# jQuery Mobile divs float left

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, split

I am creating a mobile web site with jQuery Mobile. I want to split footer 4 part. But last div slips down. How can i fix this problem ?

HTML

```
<div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="footer-img"></div>
        <div class="footer-img"></div>
        <div class="footer-img"></div>
        <div class="footer-img"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.footer-img{
    width: 24.5%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I tried but result was not change

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to calculate the width using Jquery. Trying css only solutions for the footer while you are floating the boxes to the left may not work well.

Code

```
var fwidth;

//On page loads get the innewith of the footer, divide by 4 and subtract 2 pixels then Change footer-im width
fwidth = $("#footer").innerWidth() / 4 - 2;
$(".footer-img").width(fwidth);

//On resizing the the browser window get the innewith of the footer, divide by 4 and subtract 2 pixels then Change footer-im width
$(window).resize(function() {
fwidth = $("#footer").innerWidth() / 4 - 2;
$(".footer-img").width(fwidth);
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/omtkvne9/)**

Comment: A navbar is easier or grid with 4 blocks which is the same as navbar but no buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your solution is working on jsfiddle but not working on my computer. Result is same now

Comment: @Muhammed Yusuf Taşkesenligil -- as Omar pointed out use a grid in the footer  -- https://jsfiddle.net/zbocwr8L/ --- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/grids/#&ui-state=dialog